# Reflection and Generics get value of property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics, reflection

i am trying to implement a generic method which allows to output csv file

```
public static void WriteToCsv<T>(List<T> list) where T : new()
    {
        const string attachment = "attachment; filename=PersonList.csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");                   

        bool isFirstRow = true;
        foreach (T item in list)
        {                
            //Get public properties
            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperties();

            while (isFirstRow)
            {
                WriteColumnName(propertyInfo);
                isFirstRow = false;
            }

            Type type = typeof (T);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (PropertyInfo info in propertyInfo)
            {
                   //string value ???? I am trying to get the value of the property info for the item object

            }                
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);                
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

but I am not able to get the value of the object's property

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind that there are some boundary cases here, such as indexer properties.  The simple GetValue call will throw on an indexer property, so you have to decide if you want to explicitly ignore them (can check that number of indexer parameters is 0) or handle them in some other way.  Depending on your application, you might also want to handle Nullable properties differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
object value = info.GetValue(item, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperties(); 
var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
```