# Looping through Objects properties

Tags: c#

How can i loop over an object's properties and get the value of a property.
i have an object that has several properties filled with data. the user specifies what property he wants to view by providing the name of the property, and i need to search for the property in the object and return its value to the user.
 How can i achieve this?
i wrote the following code to get the property but couldn't get the value of that prop:

```
 public object FindObject(object OBJ, string PropName)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] pi = OBJ.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
        {
            if (pi[i].PropertyType.Name.Contains(PropName))
                return pi[i];//pi[i] is the property the user is searching for,
                             // how can i get its value?
        } 
        return new object();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop Through An Objects Properties In C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957783/loop-through-an-objects-properties-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2737663/310574 also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (code inserted inline):

```
public object FindObject(object OBJ, string PropName)
{
    PropertyInfo[] pi = OBJ.GetType().GetProperties();
    for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pi[i].PropertyType.Name.Contains(PropName))
        {
            if (pi[i].CanRead)                     //Check that you can read it first
               return pi[i].GetValue(OBJ, null);   //Get the value of the property
        }
    }
    return new object();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To get the value from a `PropertyInfo`, you call [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) :) I doubt that you *really* want to be getting the name of the property *type* mind you. I suspect you want:

```
if (pi[i].Name == PropName)
{
    return pi[i].GetValue(OBJ, null);
}
```

Note that you should probably make sure that the property isn't an indexer, and is readable and accessible etc. LINQ is a good way of filtering things, or you could just use [`Type.GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty.aspx) to get straight to the property with the required name, instead of looping - and *then* perform all the validation that you need.

You should also consider following naming conventions and using a `foreach` loop. Oh, and I'd probably either return null or throw an exception if the property can't be found. I can't see how returning a new empty object would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`pi[i].GetValue(OBJ,null);` is the function to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static object FindObject(object obj, string propName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => pi.Name == propName && pi.CanRead)
        .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(obj, null))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) method passing in the object to get the value for.

```
public object FindObject(object OBJ, string PropName)      
{          
    PropertyInfo[] pi = OBJ.GetType().GetProperties();           

    for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)           
    {               
        if (pi[i].Name == PropName)                   
        {
            return pi[i].GetValue(OBJ, null);
        }
    }            

    return new object();       
}
```

All reflection types, including PropertyInfo are bound to the class. You have to pass in the instance of the class in order to get any instance-related data.